# -stringByAppendingString: not working

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I need to concatenate two NSStrings , I wrote the code below:

```
NSString *reverseResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@""];
NSString *zero = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"0"];
NSString *one = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"1"];
int modRes;
while (num != 0) {
    modRes = num;
    modRes = num % 2;
    if (modRes == 0)
        [reverseResult stringByAppendingString:zero];
    else
        [reverseResult stringByAppendingString:one];
    num = num / 2;
}
```

When I debug the code I see that the "stringByAppendingString" is not doing what I need (reverseResult stays @"", even though it gets to that row).

Is there something wrong with the code?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

stringByAppendingString returns a new string, it doesn't modify the existing one. You have to store the result in a variable.

Comment: if you want the same string to be appended you can do it on the same line: `myStringToAppend = [myStringToAppend stringByAppendingString:@"new piece of string to add"];`